# How do I use jQuery slideToggle if all divs hidden otherwise fade between divs?

Tags: jquery, fade, slidetoggle

On my company website i'm trying to create a Meet the Team section whereby i have a row of four thumbnails of team members and i want their bio's to slide/fade in below when a thumbnail clicked and slide/fade out when the thumbnail is clicked again.

I have achieved this with the code below:

```
$(".team-desc").hide(); //hide all the team descriptions


  $(".team-toggle").click(function () {
        var divname= this.getAttribute('data-team');
          $("#"+divname)
          .slideToggle("slow")
          .animate(
            { opacity: 1 },
            { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
            )
          .siblings()
          .hide();
        });
```

This works as expected so almost there.

What i'd like to achieve is a way to fade between bios if one bio is already visible so as to avoid the collapsing and then expanding effect that i currently get when switching between team member bios.

I'm assuming this needs to be done by testing if any bio div is currently visible but i'm not sure how to factor the code to make this work.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

for information my html markup is:

```
<li class="team-toggle" data-team="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></li>
```

and

```
<div class="team-desc" id="<?php the_title(); ?>">
   <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I've since come across the following jQuery tutorial which is pretty much exactly what i was trying to achieve: [link](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".team-desc").hide();

$(".team-toggle").click(function () {
    var divname = $(this).data('team'),
        visible = $(".team-desc").is(':visible');

    if (visible) {
        $("#"+divname).fadeIn('slow').siblings(':visible').fadeOut('slow');
    }else{
        $("#"+divname)
              .slideToggle("slow")
              .animate(
                { opacity: 1 },
                { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
               )
              .siblings()
              .hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always select all of your elements with `$.each()` and manipulate them using something like:

```
$('.your-elements').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
        $('.your-elements').not($(this)).stop().animate({
           // ...
        });
    } else {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            // ...
        });
        $('.your-elements').not($(this)).stop().animate({
           // ...
        });
    }
    });
});
```